# T-SQL Open transaction without closing it within same procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I would like to begin transaction at some point in my procedure without having to comitt it or rollback.

Example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.so_example
AS

    /*
        some code here 
                        */
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

GO
```

But while executing such procedure (`exec dbo.so_example`) I got this error:

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure so_example, Line 0 [Batch Start
>   Line 11] Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching
>   number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current
>   count = 1.

Is there any way to switch off this validation or open transaction in diffrent way?

Comment: No way to do that

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I want to unify transaction and request/response handling. Each interface at beginning will exec logRequest procedure which will save and parse request and begin/save transaction. At the end of interface I want to call getResponse procedure which will create response and handle transaction depending on error

Comment: I'd suggest to rethink the whole workflow :/

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with distributed transactions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql)

Comment: How? I can't see it